# How to create a regex that matches a website and only a particular subdomain?

Tags: regex

I have been struggling to create a regex that matches the site cnn.com and its subdomain m.cnn.com. I have the following:
`https?://(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?cnn\.com/\d+/\d+/\d+/\w+/\w+`

However, my trouble is with links such as the following:

`https://www.cnn.com/2022/02/11/politics/ukraine-russia-latest-news-friday-intl/index.html`

`https://www.cnn.com/2022/02/11/politics/trump-mar-a-lago-documents-archives/index.html`

After the 2022/02/11 part, there can be any kind of text. Sometimes short, other times long. It's pretty variable. I tried `w+`, but that is limited in its scope.

What modification can I make to my regex so that it matches the variety of differences in such kind of URLs?

Comment: What is the advantage in this case of having both strings as one variable rather than just having two different string variables (or an array of strings)?

Comment: That'd mean I have to do appending twice, which is doubly inefficient.

Comment: Sorry, this question sounds like nonsense. If `link` is a string then it isn't also a different string. It looks like you're trying to make two separate requests. And the way to do that is... exactly that. You can use a for loop or a comprehension.

Comment: I was thinking more in the line of using OR so that both cases can be accommodated, but if not, that's fine, I can just do two requests. I thought Python can do something so simple.

Comment: Replace `\w` with `\S`, `https?://(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?cnn\.com/\d+/\d+/\d+/\w+/\S+`

Answer (score 0):

This string matches with optional https:// optional www and optional m. before cnn.com

then any length of legal string and an optional .html at the end

```
^((https:\/\/)?www.)?(m\.)?cnn.com(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]*)*(\.html)?
```